# Why can I manipulate a variable in my subroutine without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: vb.net

I am starting my VB.NET class this semester and it has been a while since I have done anything in VB.NET and I am realizing I have forgotten some of the basics. In the following example program, I do not need to pass exampleVar to the function to be able to change the value. Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim exampleVar As Integer = 0


    Sub MySub()
        exampleVar = 123
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MySub()
        TextBox1.Text = exampleVar
    End Sub
End Class
```

The textbox displays the value 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off...

```
Dim exampleVar As Integer = 0
```

The code above is declared just 1 level below your Class Form1, which means, it's a Global variable that any of the subs below the Class Form1 can access and use.

```
Sub MySub()
    exampleVar = 123
End Sub
```

The code above is a Sub that sets exampleVar to 123.

Lastly... When your form loads, you call the Sub that equates exampleVar to 123, after which, TextBox1.Text is equated to whatever value exampleVar holds, which is 123, thus it's displaying 123.

You're are doing nothing wrong if that is what you want. If you don't want to set exampleVar to 123, remove the MySub() from the Form_Load event.

Comment: Oh now I am starting to understand. I have been taking C++ classes the past year and was thinking of "Public Class Form1" as the "Main" in C++ and I guess that is incorrect.

Comment: Is bad practice to have a global variable like this? I don't know how else to be able to update the value from multiple buttons (onclick event).

Comment: @TravelinMax, It's not bad practice. Depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you want to update the value of a certain variable by multiple button clicks while retainining previous values, or getting all subs to have access to the variable, you're right about the the global variable route.

Answer (score 0):

`exampleVar` is global variable with value is equal to 0. You are updating it in `MySub()` method before displaying it.

Comment: Hmm, I am doing something wrong declaring my variables there then? I just finished a C++ class (not Visual, just console applications written in a text editor) and I'm still not completely understanding the structure of VB programs.

Comment: C++ and many other languages have also concepts like global and local variables and methods/functions. If you have successfully completed C++ course then I believe there must not be any difficulty for you to understand such a basic thing in any language. Anyhow, use Visal Studio Express Edtion for VB.NET and also read some introductory tutorials for VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

So in your example the variable declaration is inside the 'scope' of the class. That makes it accessible to anything else that is also inside the scope of the class.

If the declaration took place inside MySub(), eg:

```
Public Sub MySub()
    Dim exampleVar As Integer = 0
    exampleVar = 123
End Sub
```

it would be inaccessible outside of the scope of MySub, at which point you might have to start passing it around, but remember in general that if you do this, you will mostly be passing 'ByVal' or, by value. That means that:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal arg As Integer) 
    arg = 123
End Sub
```

Will not affect the original variable when this method is called like:

```
Dim exampleVar As Integer = 0 
...
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MySub(exampleVar)
    TextBox1.Text = exampleVar
End Sub
```

In this example, exampleVar would still be 0 - which I think is the effect you were expecting.

When objects are passed ByVal, their value is passed in, but not the original object. To affect the original variable in this manner, you might use ByRef, which passes in the object 'by reference'.

Comment: Is bad practice to have a global variable like this? I don't know how else to be able to update the value from multiple buttons (onclick event).

Comment: Not necessarily, it's not really a _global_ variable - it's just available to everything inside the scope of the form class. 

If that's what you need, then it might make sense to do things this way. You might also consider using [properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308230) - the form is after all a class.